# DatePickerIOS doesn't translate to XCUIElementTypePickerWheel for Appium automation instead shows XCUIElementTypeOthers

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, mobile, appium

I am using React Native app with DatePickerIOS control. But when I am trying to select `XCUIElementTypePickerWheel` in Appium tool, it doesn't select any elements as the date picker is translated to the `XCUIElementTypeOthers` instead. How do I make it use `XCUIElementTypePickerWheel` so that automated tests can be written easily.

Code for DatePickerIOS is very basic :

```
<DatePickerIOS mode={ this.props.mode }
        maximumDate={ this.props.maxiumDate }
        minimumDate={ this.props.miniumDate }
        />
```